# How to fix HTTP module not working in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VShtPwEkDD0) and my code looks exactly the samein the part at 5:00 yet it doesnt work. Here's my code

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.write('Hello Node')
    res.end
})

server.listen(port, function(error){
    if(error){
        console.log("Error: " + error)
    } else {
        console.log("Server is listening on port " + port)
    }

})
```

I tried using a different browser but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to call the `res.end()` method at line 6.

Just add the parenthesis, and the code should work just fine.

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.write('Hello Node')
    res.end() //call this method
})

server.listen(port, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error)
    } else {
        console.log("Server is listening on port " + port)
    }

})
```